# How to select radiobutton through @FindBy annotation in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, findby

While designing page object class we use `@FindBy(name="value")` i.e *FindBy* with name.

SO below code to find an webpage's textbox like username field.
`@FindBy(name="username")`

```
WebElement txtboxUname;
```

........//Inside testfunction we call this `txtboxUname` like below

`txtboxuname.sendKeys("purnendu");`

So for radio button page object how we define it through `@FindBy`???
Following code is not working

`@FindBy(name="radio")`

`List<WebElement> radioBtnSelectTrip`;

.......call inside function

`radioBtnSelectTrip.get(0).click();`

The above `@FindBy` technique is not working for radio button.can you please help how to define `radiobutton` through `@FindBy` and use it through Pagefactory

Answer (score 2):

There are several techniques for `UI` mapping. While using `@FindBy` to map `UI` elements it is possible to map the element with `xpath`. However, you want to make sure the `xpath` is correct and only returns the target `radio`. See an example of how to find an element with `xpath` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678617/selenium-phpunit-select-element-by-label-text/28679028#28679028)

Explore more about the `Annotation Type FindBy` [here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBy.html#xpath%28%29)

And,

```
@FindBy(name="radio")

List<WebElement> radioBtnSelectTrip;
```

will not return you ONE radio rather a list. To perform an action on a specific radio you need to add additional filter. such as`if` condition to match a *unique* criteria on the target radio button.

**Edit** Added code to explore how `FindBy` can be implementation in finding a specific radio

```
@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "[type='radio'][value='roundtrip']")
public WebElement roundTrip;

@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "[type='radio'][value='oneway']")
public WebElement oneWay;
```

Comment: `@FindBy` can return a `List`: https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBy.html

Comment: @SiKing I am saying yes as well.

Comment: OP further specified he is calling `radioBtnSelectTrip.get(0).click();`. So I do not understand your "additional filter" comment.

Comment: @SiKing You are asking me two different things. You know `radioBtnSelectTrip.get(0).click();` will not necessarily  return the **target** element OP may want. That's what I meant by adding `such as if condition to match a unique criteria on the target radio button` and I never said `@FindBy` will not return `List`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. If you want to return a radio button, you probably want to select by it's `type`: `@FindBy(xpath="//input[@type='radio']")`.

Comment: Thanks alot saifur and Siking for your quick answer.

Comment: <td width="67%">
<b>
<font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
<input type="radio" checked="" value="roundtrip" name="tripType"/>
              Round Trip                  
<input type="radio" value="oneway" name="tripType"/>
              One Way
</font>
</b>
</td>

Comment: above is the HTML description of the radio button on my page..so how can i defined through @FIndBy and how can i access the radio button in my test please provide me the code.

Comment: @purnendusekkharrath If you need to clarify your question, do not put it in the Comments. Edit your original question!